# Count by column an one condition in one of 3 other columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have columns A,B,C,D with numbers

I need count how many rows where A>50 AND at least one of B,C,D > 20

I can do it with only one condition:

```
=COUNTIFS(A1:A100,">50",B1:B100,">20")
```

but not understand how to add OR condition to  it

if I do:

```
=COUNTIFS(A1:A100,">50",B1:B100,">20",C1:C100,">20",D1:D100,">20")
```

It will treat all conditions as AND, but I need it in form: `A>50`& `(B>20|C>20|D>20)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use SUMPRODUCT:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A1:A100>50)*((B1:B100>20)+(C1:C100>20)+(D1:D100>20)>0))
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe:

```
=SUM(--(MMULT((A1:A100>50)*(B1:D100>20),{1,1,1})>0))
```